# return datareader to datagridview using class

Tags: c#, datagridview

for code improvment I have made class `DbConnection` to not repte connection codes and gridviewCodes many times but I am getting error that says

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object' C#

please anyone can help me to get over it

**DbConnection class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

using System.Configuration;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace EntranceApp
{
    class DbConnection
    {
        MySqlConnection Conn;
        string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnSet"].ConnectionString;

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
            Conn.Open();
        }
        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            Conn.Close();
        }
        public void ExecuteQueries(string QurStr)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QurStr, Conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public MySqlDataReader ReadData(string QurStr)
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QurStr, Conn))
            {
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return dr;
            }
        }
        public DataTable GetDataTable(string QurStr)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QurStr, Conn))
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + " \n DisplayDataGridView ");
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling the DbConnection class**

```
   private void FillDataGridViewShop()
    {

        string cmdstr = @"SELECT shop_id AS 'Shop ID', 
                                 location AS 'Location'
                          FROM   shops";
        try
        {
            dbConn.OpenConnection();

            dGVStand.DataSource = dbConn.GetDataTable(cmdstr);


            lblCountShop.Text = dGVShop.RowCount.ToString();
            this.dGVShop.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            this.dGVShop.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            this.dGVShop.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            dbConn.CloseConnection();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why a method `DisplayDataGridView` returns a single `Object` at all? Make it `void` and finished

Comment: @TimSchmelter to return data from the method in the calling part is it wrong ? .. it was at first `void` but i change it when i was trying to get of it of the error i talked about

Comment: What you want to return? If you want to return the `DataTable` don't return `Object` but `DataTable`. And don't name this method  `DisplayDataGridView` but `GetData`

Comment: your open conection method will actualy Close and dispose the Connection...  you need to re write all of it

Comment: @Thorarins uh you mean I have to remove all the using in the whole class  am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using the method `DisplayDataGridView` to get a DataTable after executing a query, so Its better to change the return type to `DataTable` from object. Declare and initialize `dt`, the DataTable out side the try block and use a single return statement to after catch. So you will get a populated DataTable if the query executed successfully and a fresh one in case of error. Now its better to change the function name as well. Finally the method signature will looks like the following:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string QurStr)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QurStr, Conn))
        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        { 
           dt.Load(dr);
        }           
     }
     catch (Exception ex )
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()+ " \n DisplayDataGridView ");
     }
     return dt;
}
```